# How to call action and set state in componentDidUpdate() in react and redux (prevent infinte loop)

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have a navigation bar in my project which is common for all
and it has a input text field

```
<input
    placeholder="Search Assets"
    type="text"
    id="searchTerm"
    onChange={this.searchAsset}
    value={this.state.searchValue}
/>
```

and function onChange i am redirecting to library page

```
searchAsset = event => {
    const searchValue = event.target.value;
    this.setState({ searchValue });
    if (searchValue.trim().length > 2) {
      this.props.history.push(`/company/library?q=${searchValue}`);
    }
  };
```

and in library page i am calling search action in componentDidMount()

```
componentDidMount() {
    const params = new URLSearchParams(this.props.location.search);
    const q = params.get('q');
    this.setState({ searchValue: q });
    this.props.actions.searchAssets({ page: 0, searchString: q });
  }
```

Now issue is whenever i am searching again - Suppose initially i searched "image" and after getting the result i deleted the text in top nav and again searched text "download"
I am not getting any response from backend

Right now i want to achieve this issue with

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProp, prevState) {
    const params = new URLSearchParams(this.props.location.search);
    const q = params.get('q');
    if (q !== prevState.searchValue) {
      this.props.actions.searchAssets({ page: 0, searchString: q });
    }
  }
```

and i am getting the error **Maximum update depth exceeded. This can happen when a component repeatedly calls setState inside componentWillUpdate or componentDidUpdate.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Issue

Your `componentDidUpdate` version doesn't quite match the `componentDidMount` version. You always compare `q` to `prevState.searchValue` but don't update the state so the comparison is false on the next update. `q !== prevState.searchValue` never results in false and you appear to enqueue a bunch of actions that result in render looping.

## Solution

Cache the current search result for the next state update comparison so the effect is run only when a *new* search query arrives.

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProp, prevState) {
  const params = new URLSearchParams(this.props.location.search);
  const q = params.get('q');
  if (q !== prevState.searchValue) {
    this.setState({ searchValue: q }); // <-- update state with search value
    this.props.actions.searchAssets({ page: 0, searchString: q });
  }
}
```

Comment: Okay I understand and updated the code and it works fine.
But whenever i am visiting my library page normally without any search params
i am getting empty page

Comment: @chaitanyagupta That seems like an issue your library page should handle if it's mounted and there is no `q` query string value. Can you describe in a bit more detail what/how is empty? A bit out of scope for this question, but if you ask a new question specific to *that* issue then feel free to @ me here and I can take a look if I have time. At the least you'll get more eyes on it more quickly.

Comment: this secenario is fixed - http://localhost:6075/company/library?q=dow


now i am getting empty on http://localhost:6075/company/library

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66778761/how-to-use-tinymce-editor-in-formik-react

please see this question

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66889482/remove-specific-tag-from-innerhtml-and-render-it-on-react-page/66889579?noredirect=1#comment118238612_66889579

Hi Drew Please see this question

Comment: @chaitanyagupta Both the suggestion in the comment and Flo's answer seem to be what you are asking for. Is there a concern or are they not quite what you are looking for?

Comment: I want to know more efficient answer because dangerouslySetInnerHTML is not safe
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66889482/remove-specific-tag-from-innerhtml-and-render-it-on-react-page/66889579?noredirect=1#comment118238612_66889579