# Remove specific tag from innerHtml and render it on react page

Tags: javascript, reactjs, innerhtml, dangerouslysetinnerhtml

I created a blog web application using react and redux and in my blog there is 4 fields id,title,seoName and description and for input in description i am using tiny Mce text editor
Now i want to display the text saved in description field of Blog class which is in HTML
and truncate it using elllipses
[image]

This is stored in database

```
    {
        "_id" : ObjectId("60640e75f7bafb14f6563d52"),
        "title" : "Improve Your Developer Experience With Nuxt Components",
        "seoName" : "improve-your-developer-experience-with-nuxt-components",
        "description" : "<p><img src=\"https://webconnect-upload.s3.amazonaws.com/160x00u0xj1ny179o3a1fd07kl26/screenshot-from-2021-03-31-11-22-39.png\" alt=\"\" width=\"802\" height=\"274\" /></p>\n<h2 id=\"introduction\">Introduction</h2>\n<p>The Nuxt team has introduced&nbsp;<strong><a href=\"https://www.npmjs.com/package/@nuxt/components\" target=\"_blank\" rel=\"nofollow noopener noreferrer\">@nuxt/components</a></strong>&nbsp;module with the purpose to make Nuxt development faster and to make you, as a developer, more productive. This module comes with amazing features and options that will improve your development experience with Nuxt. No matter if you&rsquo;re just starting out or an advanced user,&nbsp;<a href=\"https://github.com/nuxt/components\" target=\"_blank\" rel=\"nofollow noopener noreferrer\">@nuxt/components</a>&nbsp;provides a range of options from the simplest setup to advance configurations that will certainly benefit your projects.</p>\n<p>In a nutshell, this module automatically scans, imports and registers Vue components found in the&nbsp;<strong><code>~/components</code></strong>&nbsp;directory, so that we don't have to write import statements when we use them in either pages, layouts or even within components.</p>\n<p>&nbsp;</p>\n<blockquote>\n<p><em>This module parses your template and automatically includes the component in the file where you are using it such as a page, layout or even a component. Because Nuxt.js uses automatic code splitting to split your pages by default this module works perfect as it will only contain the components that are used on that page. Also, if you use a component in more than 2 pages, Nuxt.js will automatically create a shared chunk for them thanks to the magic of WebPack.</em></p>\n</blockquote>",
}
```

I just want to display only truncated text (removing images from description)
and rest of the things by clicking  on read more.

Right now i am using
Suggest if there is any other efficient way

```
                  <p className="m-0px truncateBlogDesc"
                  dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: e.description }}
                  ></p>
```

Comment: I know this is not an answer to your question. But,why don't you just hide the <img> tag inside truncateBlogDesc with the css?

Comment: Do you want something that is more efficient, or something that is more safe? (Or both?) If you feel using `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` isn't safe then don't use it. Can you clarify what you are looking for? If concern about security you can check out [DOMPurify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/dompurify). It also sounds like you want to truncate the raw HTML string. For this you'd need to process the string and keep a stack of the tags processed so if you truncate in the middle of an open tag you can close it.

Comment: I solved the issue with DomPurify Thanks Drew :-)
Also Please see this question @DrewReese https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66963413/how-to-re-execute-componentdidmount-again-when-i-click-the-component-again

Answer (score 1):

You could use a regex to replace every <img ..> tag in your string (`e.description`).

For example :

```js
var tmp = inner.replace(/<img .*?>/g,"<text>"); # remove <text> to replace the tag with an empty string ​
```

Could you try  :

```js
​<p className="m-0px truncateBlogDesc" ​dangerouslySetInnerHTML={{ __html: e.description.replace(/<img .*?>/g,"") }} ​></p>
```

Comment: if i want to display only <p> tag is what will be the regex (ignore all tags and display only <p> tag)
Actually i dont know how to write regex
and one more thing this way of rendering innerHTML is efficient or not?

Comment: Nah the regex I provided just removes <img > tag (and content inside) in a string, it does not affect any other string that doesn't match a <img> tag.
I'm not sure it is the "best way" to do that (I'm not a react expert so maybe i'm wrong) but if it works well for your need and your code does not need to be optimized a lot (for better performance) it will be okay. Just carefully read the `dangerouslySetInnerHTML` documentation to know what you are doing (doc says you have to use it with caution).

Comment: Okay Thanks for advice

Comment: If you are ok with hiding all html tags except for the p tags, then simple css would do it.
You could toggle a class .readmore on your element. and use something like:

.readmore *:not(p) {
    display: none;
}

Answer (score 0):

I used this function to do something similar. Maybe it will help you. This function trips all htmls and returns only the texts.

```
const htmlparser = require('htmlparser2');

function stripTags(html) {
  let strippedHtml = '';
  // noinspection JSUnusedGlobalSymbols
  const parser = new htmlparser.Parser({
    ontext(text) {
      strippedHtml +=  text;
    },
  });
  parser.write(html);
  parser.end();

  return strippedHtml;
};
```

Comment: is html parser is library?

Comment: Yes. But, I think it should be already be installed in your node_modules as a dependency for other packages.