# How to re execute componentDidMount again when i click the component again?

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, react-router

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

This is my top navbar of my project and
[![enter image description here][2]][2]

when i click on blogs button list of all blogs will rendered and in this component i have a search option now when i have search text let's say "vue" then i will get the required result

```
handleSubmit = values => {
    const { size } = this.state;
    this.setState({ searchString: values.searchString, isSearch: true });
    SearchSchema.searchString = this.state.searchString;
    this.props.history.push(`/blogs?q=${values.searchString}`);
    this.props.actions.loadBlogs({ page: 0, size, searchString: values.searchString });
  };
```

and this is componentDidMount of Blog Component

```
componentDidMount = () => {
    const { size } = this.state;
    const params = new URLSearchParams(this.props.location.search);
    const q = params.get('q');
    if (q) {
      this.setState({ searchString: q, isSearch: true });
      this.props.actions.loadBlogs({ page: 0, searchString: q, size });
    } else {
      this.setState({ searchString: '', isSearch: false });
      this.props.actions.loadBlogs({ page: 0, size });
    }
  };
```

After getting the result when i again clicked on Blogs from Top Navbar (in screenshot) url is getting changed but not getting all the blogs

```
<Link className="nav-link" to="/blogs">
            Blogs
          </Link>
```

screenshot with search result and url will be  http://localhost:8075/blogs?q=vue
same screenshot is also applicable when i clicked blogs button again url is getting changed but blogs is not updated http://localhost:8075/blogs

i solved the issue with this

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProp, prevState) {
    const { size } = this.state;
    const params = new URLSearchParams(this.props.location.search);
    const q = params.get('q');
    if (q !== prevState.searchString) {
      console.log('-------- in if -----------');
      this.setState({ searchString: q });
      this.props.actions.loadBlogs({ page: 0, size });
    }
  }
```

but not sure this is correct or not
and also by using this i am still getting the previous value in search input field

Comment: can you show us how you defined your `<Router>` block?

Comment: Agreed, can we see your routing, and also more of this blog component for how it may need to respond to updated URLs?

Comment: This is what i write in route.js
 { path: '/blogs', name: 'Blogs', component: Blogs },

Comment: componentDidUpdate(prevProp, prevState) {
    const { size } = this.state;
    const params = new URLSearchParams(this.props.location.search);
    const q = params.get('q');
    if (q !== prevState.searchString) {
      console.log('-------- in if -----------');
      this.setState({ searchString: q });
      this.props.actions.loadBlogs({ page: 0, size });
    }
  }
i solved the issue using this but my search input field is still having the same value
and i am not sure this is the correct way or not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done with the help of `componentDidUpdate`, you can compare search `params` in `componentDidUpdate`, and can perform your changes when they are differet.

### Solution:

```
componentDidUpdate(prevProps) {
  if(prevProps.location.search !== this.props.location.search) {
     this.init(); 
  }    
}

componentDidMount {
    this.init();
};

 init = () => {
   const { size } = this.state;
    const params = new URLSearchParams(this.props.location.search);
    const q = params.get('q');
    if (q) {
      this.setState({ searchString: q, isSearch: true });
      this.props.actions.loadBlogs({ page: 0, searchString: q, size });
    } else {
      this.setState({ searchString: '', isSearch: false });
      this.props.actions.loadBlogs({ page: 0, size });
    }    
 }
```

Comment: this.setState({ searchString: '', isSearch: false });
infiinte loop error

Comment: Did you apply `if(prevProps.location.search !== this.props.location.search) {` this condition in your code?